# New Line at Every Full Stop in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently connect to a SQL Database using ASP.NET MVC. I am fairly new to this concept and I am looking to make something from the database displayed in a more readable format.

At the minute, I have a field within the Database Table called description and my application just dumps everything that is in that field on to the page. I am wanting to make it easier to read by having a brand new line for each sentence. So basically i want to start a new line at every full stop.

This is my view...

```
@model DataIntelligence.Models.Error

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js">      </script>
<script>
function goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
</script>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h2>Error Details</h2>
</div>

<fieldset>
<legend>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Source)</legend>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExecutionId)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ExecutionId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TfsBugId)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TfsBugId)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="display-label">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    <p> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</p>
</div>
</fieldset>
<button class="btn btn-link" onclick="goBack()">Back to List</button>
```

And this would be some sample data...

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on New Accounts Source returned error code 0xC0202092. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Help would be appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: description.replace(Environment.newline, "<br/>")

Comment: Post your html and Action code. As well as a sample of the data in the description field

Comment: added code and sample data

Comment: In the GET method, use `string.Replace()` to replace `.` (dot) with `Environment.NewLine` and then style the html element with `whitespace: pre;`

Comment: I think it would be better to have a `List<string>` and split the string up maybe in the controller, keep the logic as clean as possible in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action method format your string and put `<br />` in end of new line.

```
public ActionResult GetMyError(int id)
{
    Error model=_myDb.Get(id);
    model.Description=model.Description.Replace(". ","<br />");
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the model you need add `[DataType(DataType.Html)]` to your property.

```
class Error
{
    // your other members

    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```